# Is it possible to use the computed properties to compute another properties in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have a two computed properties like this,

```
computed: {
  id: function(){ return this.$route.query.id; },
  hasId: function(){ return this.$route.query.id !== undefined; }
}
```

how can I use `id` to compute `hasId` like this pseudo-code?

```
computed: {
  id: function(){ return this.$route.query.id; },
  hasId: function(){ return id !== undefined; }
}
```

Comment: `return id` -> `return this.id()` fixes your problem

Comment: Why don't you post it as a reply so it can get accepted?

Comment: because you can't downvote a comment and there are often gotchas in the OP's question that are only known via clarification

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use correct scope to access a vue computed property.

as you are using just `id`, it will search it in global scope and not find it and will return undefined. For getting vue computed property, you need to do: `this.id`, so your code will look like following:

```
computed: {
  id: function () { return this.$route.query.id; },
  hasId: function () { return this.id !== undefined; }
}
```

Inside a component, `this` refers to our [Vue instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html). However you can access $route and other similar function from `this`, as they are defined at `Vue.prototype`, see below code from [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/4561ecf58581b8ed852a3f9a33d3dbaf2f7f4a45/dist/vue-router.js#L406):

```
 Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$route', {
    get: function get$1 () { return this.$root._route }
 })
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please take a look at my comment to the other reply by @aaaaaa if you have time. `this.id()` should refer to the base Vue object and not the currently created component, according to my understanding. I'm sure I'm missing something but what?

Comment: @KonradViltersten updated the answer, let me know if it answers your query.

Comment: `this` is a very misused construct in javascript.  Vue really shouldn't be messing with `this` in confusing instances such as a 'computed' object.

Answer (score 6):

your pseudo code was very close.  Just change `id` to `this.id`

```
computed: {
  id: function(){ return this.$route.query.id; },
  hasId: function(){ return this.id !== undefined; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's working. According to everything I've read, in this context `this` refers to the Vue object and not the component instance itself (that's why e.g. `this.$route` works and that's the reason I can't use the new JS syntax `prop:()=>{...}`). I'd guess that `this.id()` would refer to some property `id` in the root Vue object too... What am I missing, please?

Comment: I can't speak to vuejs, but `this` refers to the object whose properties it owns.  In the case of hasId, `this` refers to `computed`.  Also if you want to use new js syntax, then `hasId() { return this.id() !== undefined; }` would be the way to go.

Comment: I don't think the `this.id()` as a function call is correct

Comment: You're right, and thanks - I've since used vue and vue decided these should be magically turned into getter properties as opposed to functions, even though they are written as functions.  I disagree with the design choice but such is vue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and I simply resolved it using a watcher. Hope it helps:

```
 <div id="app">
  <label> true or false
   <input v-model="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  </label>   
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      checkbox: false,
    },

    computed: {

      checkboxComputed(){
        return this.checkbox;
      },

      lonelyComputed(){
        console.log('who bothers?');
        }
      },

    watch: {

      checkboxComputed(value){
        if(value){
          console.log('checkboxComputed is changed!')
          return this.lonelyComputed;
        }
      }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: I resolved all of my issues with Vue in one radical move. I switched to Angular, hehe. Somehow, it works out much better for me. Not sure if it's the framework or just me, so I'm not complaining about Vue. Just that my problems went byebye after the switch, hahaha.