# How to use other computed properties inside computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying this:

```
    props: ["gameState"],
    computed: {
        cards() {
            return this.gameState.playerCards
        },
        rows() {
            let cards = this.cards();
            let max = 6;
            if (cards.length <= max)
                return [cards]

            var mid = Math.ceil(cards.length / 2);
            let return_value = [cards.slice(0, mid), cards.slice(mid)]
            return return_value
        }
    }
```

but it tells me that `this.cards is not a function`. I was looking at [Is it possible to use the computed properties to compute another properties in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41173998/6554121) which said this should be the way to use other computed properties.

Comment: Computed properties appear as, well, **properties**, not functions. You would use `let cards = this.cards`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @Phil I still get an error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"`

Comment: Is `computed` an object inside an object?

Comment: @Andrew Well I'm using `vue-loader` so it's part of an `export default` which gets transcribed.

Comment: @Andrew, you're looking at part of a Vue definition object which converts the `computed` object into javascript properties. @Phil is correct here. If you're getting an error, it's likely because `this.gameState.playerCards` is undefined at some point.

Comment: @Bert Thank you for the information. I've deleted my misleading comment.

Comment: @Bert They're a prop. Edited to include.

Comment: @A.Lau so what exactly are you passing to the `gameState` prop? Does it **always** have a `playerCards` property? If I had to guess, you're loading `gameState` data via AJAX but your component is being rendered before the data is available and you haven't assigned a default `playerCards` property.

Comment: @Phil Welp, I realised it was indeed a typo, silly me. It was called `playerHand` not `playerCards`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was explaining in comments.

```
computed: {
    cards() {
        return this.gameState.playerCards
    },
    rows() {
        let cards = this.cards;
        // if cards is ever undefined (maybe its populated asynchronously), 
        // cards.length will blow up. So, check here and return a sane
        // value when it's undefined            
        if (!cards) return []

        let max = 6;
        if (cards.length <= max)
            return [cards]

        var mid = Math.ceil(cards.length / 2);
        let return_value = [cards.slice(0, mid), cards.slice(mid)]
        return return_value
    }
}
```

Comment: `gameState` is a prop, I guess it makes sense if cards is not defined at the time

Comment: @A.Lau I understand. However, it appears sometimes, there is no `playerCards` property of `gameState`.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look at why that's the case. I'll come back to mark it once I've figured it out.

Comment: Yep, it was indeed a typo.